# Right way to detect if a variable is a jsx element or a router link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx

I have the following method:

```
const MyComponent = ({ value }) => {
  if (isRouterLink(value)) {
    return <span>Is router link</span>
  }

  if (isElement(value)) {
    return <span>Is an element</span>
  }

  return <span>Is just a string</span>
}
```

I need a way to find if `value` is an html element, or a Router Link.
From what I see, I am only seeing that html elements by parameters have a type (`value.type`) and Router Links have a $$type (`value.$$type`).
So I am doing:

```
function isRouterLink(value) {
  return !!value.$$typeof
}

function isElement(value) {
  return !!value.type
}
```

But it sounds a bit dirty since `$$typeof` seems to be private data. Is this the right way to check this?

Comment: Why do you need to do so?

Comment: Because I need to do different things depending if the parameter is an element, an object or a link